# My shell prompt looks like this: ➜ ~ git:(master) ✗. How can I get my normal prompt back?

Tags: git, bash, terminal, git-svn

My normal terminal command line has suddenly disappeared and has been replaced by this git command line `➜  ~ git:(master) ✗`.

How do I get rid of this and go back to my normal command line in Terminal? I on Mac OS X.

I have tried typing `exit`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd>, etc. but nothing helped.

Comment: Not an answer, but a test: try `echo $PS1` at the command line and tell us what you get.

Comment: When i do echo $PS1 i get this "${ret_status}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know your problem , You are using `zsh`, right?

If so, you should add `export PS1=xxxxx` to `~/.zshrc`, not `~/.bashrc`.

Or you just don't use `zsh` , input `bash` and switch to `bash.input` `chsh -s /bin/bash` to change the default shell to `bash`.

Answer (score 7):

You must have installed something (I'm not sure what) that modified your prompt to give you context-sensitive information about the Git repository (if any) you're in.

Simply adding

```
export PS1="\h:\W \u\$ "
```

at the very bottom of your

- `~/.bash_profile` file, if you use `bash`, or
- `~/.zshrc` file, if you use `zsh`,

and then sourcing that file (or restarting Terminal) should rid you of that fancy colourful prompt.

Comment: I added export PS1="\h:\W \u\$ " to the bottom of my .bash_profile but it didnt make any difference

Comment: There was zsh installed and and when i unistalled it i got rid of the multicoloured git master command line

Comment: @user3543449 Ahhh that makes sense! I assumed you were using `bash`. If you still want to use `zsh` as your shell but without the colourful prompt, try adding export PS1="\h:\W \u\$ " at the end of your `~/.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when getting my head around zsh and git.
I created a git repo in the wrong folder and started seeing this zsh context.
Because I didn't want a repo in this directory I removed the git information with:

> rm -R .git

Note you will only want to do this if you have an invalid git repository.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your system or you change something involuntarily. You must have download oh-my-zsh and set your default terminal from bash to zsh. Oh-my-zsh has many different themes, all these themes have different appearances and provide more efficient functions, git information is one of them. The default theme of oh-my-zsh is "robbyrussell" and it just looks like your shell prompt. You can go to "~/.oh-my-zsh/themes" to choose your favorite theme and apply it to the configuration file "./zshrc". I know you have solved the problem by uninstalled the zsh and use the original bash, I just want to tell you the essential reason of this problem. And oh-my-zsh truly provides some convenience which helps you use the command line, maybe you should try it again!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you entered "git init" like I did. It took me a while to figure this out, but when you entered "git init" you created a hidden git folder named ".git".

You can see the folder by going to your home directory and typing "ls -a".

Simply remove the file (rm -rf .git), and the prompt will magically disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Open your ZSH config file

> sudo vim ~/.zshrc

and paste below command at the bottom of the file

> PROMPT='${ret_status} %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} '

this will show current directory

Answer (score 2):

Use this following command:

```
git config oh-my-zsh.hide-info 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem. Sharing how I resolved for my future self.

When switching to zsh in home/username, the shell shows git:(master). This is due to 2 things:
1. You have installed a Git package for ZSH
2. You have likely created a .git repo under home/username so zsh is picking it up from your current location.

Steps to resolve:
1. Type `ls -a` into terminal and you will be able to see .git and .gitconfig files
2. Move .git and .gitconfig files to your specified git repository folder with `mv .git ./git_repositories/` and `mv .gitconfig ./git_repositories/`
3. type `bash` into terminal then type `zsh` into terminal and it should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if for some reason you get the

```
override r--r--r-- bunty_home/staff for .git/objects/pack/pack-f76e6a02ba4d161b1b453179ba12835649ce2ace.pack?
```

and after pressing `Enter` it tells you

```
access denied
```

just find the directory where you have your .git, (if you can't see it, turn on the hidden files). and then move the folder / files to the bin

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a few command line tools that work together with Git that add those customizations.

In my case after installing [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) I got my `~/.bashrc` file updated with Drush-specific customizations, which in this case addded a green `(master *) $` to the prompt, no matter where I was (*very* annoying).

Fixed it by commenting out the block after `# Include Drush prompt customizations.` in my `~/.bashrc` and then `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score -1):

I also has this problem like: "➜  ~ git:(master) ✗"  on the Mac OS X. Because I type the command "git init".

When I type the command "rm -R .git", it comes back into normal command line in Terminal. PS: I use zsh.

Answer (score -3):

if you having seen the (master) in somewhere your folder. try this

```
git rm .git
```

It will automatically remove the master

Answer (score -3):

Typing `rm -R .git` will take you back