# I want to get rid of this "git:(master) ✗" on my terminal

Tags: git

Sorry I'm new using Git.

I typed `git init` and I missed to do this command first:

```
git config - -global user.name “Charles”
```

I'm using (zsh).

`q` didn't work, resulting in this message :

> zsh: command not found: q

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's nothing to do with git but with the way you set up your zsh. You probably got something like `oh my zsh` or the like (with a git module) that shows you your branch and the commit status of your repository if your in a git directory.

Comment: You're not "in" git, you're in your shell, from which you can execute `git` commands, as well as a plethora of other commands. What did you expect `q` to do? Are you trying to fix your shell prompt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My shell prompt looks like this: ➜ ~ git:(master) ✗. How can I get my normal prompt back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351213/my-shell-prompt-looks-like-this-%e2%9e%9c-gitmaster-%e2%9c%97-how-can-i-get-my-normal-pro)

Answer (score 2):

Reading your question again it seems like you're thinking that you're in some kind of git mode and that `git` is showing you that prompt. That's not the case. You're in your normal shell still.

You probably got a script somewhere that changes the `PS1` shell variable when you're in a directory that's a git repository (oh-my-zsh got a git module that does this for example). You can use your shell just as normal and also use `git config --global user.name “Charles”` still. Once you `cd` out of the directory the git text should be gone.

For example my shell prompt looks like this for a normal directory:

```
~/Documents  ᐅ
```

And like this for a git repository:

```
~/git-repository (master ✔) ᐅ
```

My `PS1` variable contains:

```
~/git-repository (master ✔) ᐅ echo $PS1
%{$PROMPT_SUCCESS_COLOR%}%~%{$reset_color%} %{$GIT_PROMPT_INFO%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$GIT_DIRTY_COLOR%}$(git_prompt_status) %{$reset_color%}%{$PROMPT_PROMPT%}ᐅ%{$reset_color%}
```

The `%{$GIT_PROMPT_INFO%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$GIT_DIRTY_COLOR%}$(git_prompt_status)` part is responsible for showing the git message and removing it would get rid of the extra git message for me.

If you want to completely get rid of it look if you installed something like `oh-my-zsh` and activated a git-module there, or look for a shell script of yours that changes the

Comment: @CharlesCruz I wouldn't really call that resolved then... `.git` is the folder git uses to actually store the repository data, if you remove it the directory is just a normal directory again.

Comment: If you really want to get rid of the git text you should look for some script you installed that changes the `PS1` shell variable. But the text doesn't really do anything beside looks anyways so don't know if it's so bad.