# Shell errors and unwanted "master" in prompt after installing git

Tags: git, prompt, bash

I installed Git and now when I open Terminal I get the following:

```
-bash: /Users/Lior/.bash_profile: line 21: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /Users/Lior/.bash_profile: line 23: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351213/my-shell-prompt-looks-like-this-gitmaster-how-can-i-get-my-normal-pro) and tried the following

```
Lior (master #) ~ $ echo $PS1
\[\033[0;35m\]\u\[\033[0;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0;34m\] \W $ \[\033[0m\]

Lior (master #) ~ $ zsh
\[\033[0;35m\]\u\[\033[0;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0;34m\] \W $ \[\033[0m\]bash

bash: __git_ps1: command not found

Lior ~ $
```

There is no `(master #)` anymore but when I restart the shell `(master #)` shows again.

How can I get rid of master permanently?

Comment: Open `/Users/Lior/.bash_profile:` and check Line 21. It seems a quotation mark is missing. Quotation marks are expected to be in a pair.

Comment: `# Enable tab completion
source ~/git-completion.bash

# colors!
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

# Change command prompt
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"`

This is everything I have, there is no line 21 or 23.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than pasting the file contents into a comment; it's all-but impossible to read this way.

Comment: Also how did you install Git? It's likely whatever you did to install Git gave you the option to also update your prompt.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Git you (apparently) also configured it to [display your Git branch in your prompt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh). That's what the `$(__git_ps1)` is doing, it's invoking the [`__git_ps1` function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9f0b4dd0b8/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L238) and including its output in your prompt.

Like the error message says, it appears something (either you, or something you installed) has mangled or malformed `/Users/Lior/.bash_profile`. Take a look at the contents and see if you can fix the mis-quoting, otherwise share the contents of the file in the question.

Now you just need to remove `__git_ps1` from your prompt. As the installation instructions note, this is done by either including it in your `PS1` or setting your `PROMPT_COMMAND` to invoke it. Take a look in your `.bash_profile` for any mention of `__git_ps1` and remove / fix it. Remember to back up the file if you're uncertain what you're doing, so you can restore it if it doesn't work.