# After git commit, push then command line are changed

Tags: git, zsh

I just commit with message that "blah blah ~ ... in wip". and command changed like below  picture. before the commit it wasn't and blank on this here. has anyone know this why happened?
[image]

Comment: Your shell has a plugin which tries to display your repository state in its prompt.

Comment: I updated your tags assuming you're using zsh (that looks like a zsh prompt), but if that's wrong, update the [tag:zsh] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell is showing the current state - Your workspace (~/Doc/G/ecg-dbn) and Current git branch (master wip).

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351213/my-shell-prompt-looks-like-this-gitmaster-how-can-i-get-my-normal-pro), to remove it, you can try adding `export PS1=xxxxx` to `~/.zshrc`, if you are using zsh

Comment: oh thanks. thats work on mine.

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark as answer so others can easily find it in the future too!